# MySQL select rows between a range on a text column

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a table named basicinfo and one of column named as iepNo and it has values based on a specific format e.g

```
m-195001
m-195002
m-195003 and so on.
```

I want  to get record based on the given iepNo range. e.g i want to get iepNo between `m-233` to `m-334`

As of now I am using this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM basicinfo 
WHERE iepNo BETWEEN "M-100" AND "M-200"
```

but it is returning 2631 rows but actually, I should get only 100 rows between `m-100` and `m-200`. The column iepNo is of type `varchar(13)`.

Kindly guide me how I can resolve this issue.

Comment: Do you mean between `m-233` and `m-334` or `m-233xxx` and `m-334xxx`  or `m-xxx233` and `m-xxx334` The numbers in your example table contents are so different from the ones you say you are after

Comment: No specifically between a range. let say i want to get record between m-100 and m-200 . it should return me 100 rows right but when i try to use BETWEEN operator i am getting 2631 rows instead of 100 rows. The data in iepNo coloum is m-xxxxx f-xxxxx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could extract the ID value and cast to integer before comparing:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM basicinfo 
WHERE CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(iepNo, '-', -1) AS UNSIGNED) BETWEEN 100 AND 200;
```